# How to group variables on x axis barplot in R

Tags: r

I would like to plot this data frame. I have searched for a similar example and I couldn't find an exact match.

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1:4), 
                b=c(5:8),
                c=c(9:12),
                d=c(13:16))
row.names(x) <- c("w","x","y","z")
```

I want one barplot for the whole data frame, so each tick on the x-axis (w,x,y,z) will have four values (a,b,c,d).

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [grouped barplot](http://www.google.se/search?q=grouped+barplot+in+r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1:4), 
                b=c(5:8),
                c=c(9:12),
                d=c(13:16))

x = as.matrix(x)
row.names(x) <- c("w","x","y","z")
x = t(x)

barplot(x,beside=T, ylim=c(0,20), legend.text=rownames(x),  args.legend = c(ncol=4))
```

[image]